# How to access the next element from a unique list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list in `Python`

```
lst=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What is the best way to access the next element in the list for a given value.

For instance I would like to get:

```
next_element(lst, 'c')
# 'd' should return adjacent value of 'c'
```

What is the Pythonian way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`next()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/next) built-in function:

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

random_iterator = iter(some_list)

print(next(random_iterator)) #Output = a

print(next(random_iterator)) #Output = b
```

The syntax of `next()` is:

```
next(iterator, default)
```

1. `iterator` — `next()` retrieves next item from the `iterator`
2. `default` (optional) — this value is returned if the iterator is
   exhausted (there is no next item)

---

1. The `next()` function returns the next item from the iterator.
2. If the iterator is exhausted, it returns the `default` value passed as
   an argument.
3. If the `default` parameter is omitted and the iterator is exhausted,
   it raises `StopIteration` exception.

Answer (score 2):

This function should do what you want it to - I think utilizing the index method would be the most pythonian way to solve your issue - although I could be wrong, this is just how I thought about it.

```
def next_element(lst, element):
   idx = lst.index(element)
   return lst[idx +1]
```

Comment: using this function makes problems like "IndexError" and other things! the best way is to use ```next(iter(lst))```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
def next_element(l, elt):
    return l[l.index(elt)+1]
```

This will throw an error if the element passed into the function is the last one in the list. You might want to add some logic to handle that, depending on what you desire. Additionally, this assumes that all elements in the list are unique.

This solution however, will be very slow for a large list. `list.index` searches the list element by element until it finds the right elements, so it runs in O(n). If you are trying to walk through a list but don't want to use a loop, you can create an iterator to walk through the list as you need to.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
myit = iter(lst)
next(myit) # will return 'a'
next(myit) # will return 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a dictionary that maps the items of your list to integers, and then use the property of the modulo operation to ensure that you stay in the range of your list.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
dict = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}

def next_element(item):
    corresponding_value = dict[item]
    next_value = (corresponding_value + 1) % len(lst)
    return lst[next_value]

print("The next element in the list after f is " + next_element("f"))
```

Will return
`"The next element in the list after f is a"`